# Rotate Plotly Scatter Markers to create Wind Arrows on a Timeseries Plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Trying to create a plot displaying the wind conditions with arrows visualizing the direction of the wind at a certain timestamp.
[image: Target Visualization]

The above visualization could be created by converting the datetime index and fixing the scale-ratio.

With plotly 5.13.0 markers haven gotten the `angle` property ([Plotly Reference](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html#plotly.graph_objects.scatter.Marker.angle)), which motivated me to give it an other go using a native datetime index and scatter-markers.

The angle property can only be set once per trace as it seems, thus we'll need to loop.

#### Sample Data Generation

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(seed=13)

idx = pd.date_range("2023-07-11 10:05", "2023-07-11 11:00", freq='5min')
wind_speeds = np.random.random_sample(size=len(idx)) * 3
wind_directions = np.random.randint(0, high=3600, size=len(idx)) / 10.0
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': idx, 'V_WIND': wind_speeds, 'DIR_WIND': wind_directions})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df = df.set_index('datetime')
```

| datetime | V_WIND | DIR_WIND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-11 10:05:00 | 2.333107 | 323.2 |
| 2023-07-11 10:10:00 | 0.712624 | 296.3 |
| 2023-07-11 10:15:00 | 2.472836 | 219.7 |
| 2023-07-11 10:20:00 | 2.897248 | 142.7 |

#### Current Attempt

```py
def plot_wind(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    fig = px.line(df, y="V_WIND")
    for wind_row in df.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[wind_row[0]],
                y=[wind_row[1]['V_WIND']],
                showlegend=False,
                marker=dict(
                    color='red',
                    size=20,
                    symbol='triangle-down-open',
                    angle=[wind_row[1]['DIR_WIND']],
                )))
    fig.show()


plot_wind(df)
```

[image: Output Figure without rotated Markers]
The angle property has no effect at all. Even when fixing it to a value such as 25.0, the markers look identical. How can we get them to rotate?

Comment: I tried your code in my environment. The triangle markers are drawn in different directions. My environment is the latest version of Plotly:5.15.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @r-beginners in the comments, updating to Plotly 5.15.0 should fix the issue.

I just wanted to add that you can add the markers to the trace (with `mode='lines+markers'`) instead of adding one trace for each :

```py
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['V_WIND'],
    mode='lines+markers',
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    marker=dict(
        color='red',
        size=20,
        symbol='triangle-down-open',
        angle=df['DIR_WIND']
    )
))
```

Or

```py
fig = px.line(df, y="V_WIND")

fig.update_traces(dict(
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(
        color='red',
        size=20,
        symbol='triangle-down-open',
        angle=df['DIR_WIND']
    )
))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Whilst I had plotly 5.15.0 in the virutalenv, the plotly.js, which was rendering the plot in my Pycharm Notebook seems to be outdated. Not sure how this can be updated, but that's an other issue. If I render it directly in a browser window, it is correct. Also thanks for the shortcut, helps a lot!